# Vue defines props prototype randomly

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

The same code with the same data structure passed to the prop sets the prop as array or as object randomly.

The code fragment:

```
const props = defineProps({
    all: {
        type: Array,
        default: [],
    }
})

onBeforeMount(() => {
    console.log(props.all)
})
```

The log:
[Array proxy target prototype for the prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJVBK.png)

[Object proxy target prototype for the prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBnHN.png)

Incoming data passed to the prop is a plain array in both cases

Then I am not able to confidently use array functions on this prop because sometimes I am getting:
TypeError: u.all.sort is not a function

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Does it cause some error with your code?

Comment: Sure, TypeError: u.all.sort is not a function

Comment: Could you provide a simple [mre] that we can run to immediately see the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to provide the example. The app has a laravel backend with inertia/vue front. Any ideas what could be happening theoretically? How vue decides what type to assign to a prop even when I explicitly set it to Array?

Comment: When and how are you using this component (from laravel return or vue calling another vue) what data are you passing? Is the data being passed always the same type?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar issue [Laravel9 Inertia::render Array is converted to Vue3 props Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560500/laravel9-inertiarender-array-is-converted-to-vue3-props-object)

The problem is I sometimes pass non consecutive keys within array after server side sorting with Laravel collections and therefore Inertia sends it as object. The solution is to call ->values() on such array which restores array indexes to consecutive https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-values